# Slicing and assigning values to a 3D array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, slice

I try to assign values for the first 2 dimensions of a 2D array, while keeping the third dimension fixed. But I am getting an error.

```
Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts
```

See the code snippet below (Note that I use allcomb() from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb)).

Any idea why and how to fix?

```
A = zeros(2, 94, 10);
combs = allcomb(1:2,1:94);
A(combs(:,1), combs(:,2), 1) = 1:(2*94);
```

Note that my intention was to write a vectorized form of:

```
A = zeros(2, 94, 10);
combs = allcomb(1:2,1:94)
vals = 1:(2*94);
for k=1:length(vals)
    A(combs(k,1), combs(k,2), 1) = vals(k);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the short and elegant implementation I was looking for, using sparse() initialization:

```
A = zeros(2, 94, 10);
combs = allcomb(1:2,1:94);
vals = 1:(2*94);

%% Here it is: 
A(:,:,1) = sparse(combs(:,1), combs(:,2), vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rhs`, right hand side, of the equation needs to have the same dimensionality as the `lhs`. in this case, you're trying to assign an `N x 1` vector to an `2 x N x 1` array.

Try,

```
A = zeros(2, 94, 10);
combs = allcomb(1:2,1:94);
val = (1:2*94)';
A(combs(:,1), combs(:, 2), 1) = [val, val];
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. [val, val] is Nx2, not NxN. But anyway, I want to assign only N values, so replicating it to NxN assignments is too expensive.

Comment: fixed a typo. what are the dimensions of combs? from the context, it seems 94*94 x 2, in which case, what do gave should work. in any case, if you add more context code it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
A = zeros(2, 94, 10);
B = A;
combs = allcomb(1:2, 1:94);
vals = 1:(2*94);
for k=1:length(vals)
      A(combs(k, 1), combs(k, 2), 1) = vals(k);
end

% here it starts
val = repmat(1:94, 94, 2);
B(combs(:, 1), combs(:, 2), 1) = [val; val + 94];

isequal(A, B)   % returns 1
```

This should give you the desired result.